# Finding the closest prime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print out the closest prime to an inputted number. 
The code works for prime numbers inputted but not nonprimes. See below
I am a relatively new coder and I am new to Python

input is 16
expected result is The closest prime to 16 is 17
actual result is The closest prime to 16 is 18

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = x-1
z = x+1
counter = 0
valid = True
while valid == True:
    for i in range (2,x):
        if x%i == 0:
            counter += 1
    if counter <= 1:
        print("The closest prime to ",x," is ",x)
        valid = False
    counter = 0
    for i in range (2,y):
        if y%i == 0:
            counter += 1
    if counter <= 1:
        print("The closest prime to ",x," is ",y)
        valid = False
    counter = 0
    y -= 1
    for i in range (2,z):
        if y%i == 0:
            counter += 1
    if counter <= 1:
        print("The closest prime to ",x," is ",z)
        valid = False
    counter = 0
    z += 1
```

Comment: To save people time could you tell us what the actual error is and not just "my code is not working"?

Comment: Sorry, first post. It works for the number 17 for instance and returns the closest prime to 17 is 17. However, when I enter the number 16, it says the closest prime to 16 is 18.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Include the expected and actual output, as well the trace from your debugging attempts.

Comment: As the guidelines tell you, "make it easy for others to help you".  Your variable names don't tell us anything.  You have a "counter" that is used only as a Boolean flag.  You have three nearly identical loops for reasons you haven't explained.  You check to see whether `x` is a prime in every loop -- why?

Comment: Break this into three tasks. Task #1: Create a generator that yields the prime numbers one after the other. Task #2: Using your new generator, find the two primes numbers `a` and `b` that bracket your input `n`, that is, `a <= n <= b`. Task #3: Find the smaller of `n - a` and `b - n`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it is printing nearest prime for numbers from 1 to 100. You may try this function with random values.

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return True
    if n == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2, int(n/2) + 1):
        if n % i != 0:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True

def get_nearest_prime(n):
    if is_prime(n):
        return n
    for i in range(1, n*n):
        if is_prime(n+i):
            return n+i
        if is_prime(n-i):
            return n-i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1, 100):
        print('%s: %s' % (i, get_nearest_prime(i)))
```